# BATCH process in Scheduled Task runs twice, one immediatly after another by miliseconds

Tags: batch-file, process, scheduled-tasks

I have a Scheduled Task which runs, every 15 minutes, a very very quick BATCH process. This first "FILE1.bat" process calls another one like this:
"FILE2.bat" >> PATH\winscp_TODAYSDATE.txt
This way I can get all the output from the second into a TXT "log file".
FILE2.bat just copies files to a "DONE" folder and sends them via WINSCP to a provider, with a mput -delete, which deletes the files once successfully sent.

For some reason unknown to me, the TASK (not sure if the task itself, the FILE1 or the FILE2) runs twice (even thrice), one immediatly after another just by some miliseconds, as shown in the next text.
This  is the result when there are no files to be processed:

```
*************************************************************
******** HORA DEL REGISTRO: 21/12/2022 -  0:05:01,26 ********
*************************************************************
    ***** SIN ficheros TXT para procesar, se ha omitido el proceso y no se envia email
Success - No files to process - FICHEROS ENVIADOS: NO FILES
*************************************************************
******** HORA DEL REGISTRO: 21/12/2022 -  0:05:01,77 ********
*************************************************************
    ***** SIN ficheros TXT para procesar, se ha omitido el proceso y no se envia email
Success - No files to process - FICHEROS ENVIADOS: NO FILES
*************************************************************
******** HORA DEL REGISTRO: 21/12/2022 -  0:20:00,97 ********
*************************************************************
    ***** SIN ficheros TXT para procesar, se ha omitido el proceso y no se envia email
Success - No files to process - FICHEROS ENVIADOS: NO FILES
*************************************************************
******** HORA DEL REGISTRO: 21/12/2022 -  0:20:01,26 ********
*************************************************************
    ***** SIN ficheros TXT para procesar, se ha omitido el proceso y no se envia email
Success - No files to process - FICHEROS ENVIADOS: NO FILES
*************************************************************
******** HORA DEL REGISTRO: 21/12/2022 -  0:20:01,76 ********
*************************************************************
    ***** SIN ficheros TXT para procesar, se ha omitido el proceso y no se envia email
Success - No files to process - FICHEROS ENVIADOS: NO FILES
```

But when there are files to be processed, this happens (not always, though):

```
*************************************************************
******** HORA DEL REGISTRO: 21/12/2022 - 14:05:01,47 ********
*************************************************************
    ***** Se comprueba si hay ficheros TXT que existan para procesar: SI
    ***** Se copian los ficheros que existan para enviar antes de enviarlos a la subcarpeta COPIAS, sobreescribiendo
l:\entradas\ALS20221221135146008008649.txt
*************************************************************
******** HORA DEL REGISTRO: 21/12/2022 - 14:05:02,47 ********
*************************************************************
    ***** Se comprueba si hay ficheros TXT que existan para procesar: SI
    ***** Se copian los ficheros que existan para enviar antes de enviarlos a la subcarpeta COPIAS, sobreescribiendo
l:\entradas\ALS20221221135146008008649.txt
l:\entradas\ALS20221221135434008008649.txt
l:\entradas\ALS20221221135534008008649.txt
l:\entradas\ALS20221221135809008008649.txt
        4 archivo(s) copiado(s).
    ***** Se ejecuta WINSCP con los parametros necesarios
Connecting to x-x-x-x-x-x-x-x-x-xguro.com ...
Connected
Starting the session...
Session started.
Active session: [1] copx-x-x-xx-x-x-x-x-x-x-x-x-xguro.com
l:\entradas
/ENTRADAS
ALS20221221135146008008649.txt |          14 KB |    0,0 KB/s | binary | 100%
ALS20221221135434008008649.txt |           1 KB |    5,6 KB/s | binary | 100%
ALS20221221135534008008649.txt |           1 KB |    6,2 KB/s | binary | 100%
ALS20221221135809008008649.txt |           1 KB |    6,8 KB/s | binary | 100%
/SALIDAS
l:\SALIDAS
No file matching '*' found.
Session 'copx-x-x-xx-x-x-x-x-x-x-x-x-xguro.com' closed.
No session.
    ***** Se revisa si ha habido errores en el envio. ERRORCODE:0
    ***** Envio sin errores: Se omite el email
    ***** Resultado del envio por FTP
Success - The files were uploaded successfully. - FICHEROS ENVIADOS: SI
*************************************************************
******** HORA DEL REGISTRO: 21/12/2022 - 14:20:01,88 ********
*************************************************************
    ***** SIN ficheros TXT para procesar, se ha omitido el proceso y no se envia email
Success - No files to process - FICHEROS ENVIADOS: NO FILES
```

The files are successfully sent, fortunately and so far, but it fills the log and I'm not at ease about it...

I have looked as hard as I could, unable to find reason or solution to this behavior.
I am attaching, too, the XML of the exported TASK.

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-16"?>
<Task version="1.4" xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/windows/2004/02/mit/task">
  <RegistrationInfo>
    <Date>2022-10-28T12:14:19.6597722</Date>
    <Author>SEFRISA\eqm</Author>
    <URI>\_GyV FTP Logifrio_</URI>
  </RegistrationInfo>
  <Triggers>
    <CalendarTrigger>
      <Repetition>
        <Interval>PT15M</Interval>
        <StopAtDurationEnd>false</StopAtDurationEnd>
      </Repetition>
      <StartBoundary>2022-10-28T12:05:00</StartBoundary>
      <Enabled>true</Enabled>
      <ScheduleByDay>
        <DaysInterval>1</DaysInterval>
      </ScheduleByDay>
    </CalendarTrigger>
  </Triggers>
  <Principals>
    <Principal id="Author">
      <UserId>S-1-5-21-1834156839-169156998-926709054-1284</UserId>
      <LogonType>Password</LogonType>
      <RunLevel>HighestAvailable</RunLevel>
    </Principal>
  </Principals>
  <Settings>
    <MultipleInstancesPolicy>StopExisting</MultipleInstancesPolicy>
    <DisallowStartIfOnBatteries>false</DisallowStartIfOnBatteries>
    <StopIfGoingOnBatteries>false</StopIfGoingOnBatteries>
    <AllowHardTerminate>true</AllowHardTerminate>
    <StartWhenAvailable>true</StartWhenAvailable>
    <RunOnlyIfNetworkAvailable>false</RunOnlyIfNetworkAvailable>
    <IdleSettings>
      <StopOnIdleEnd>false</StopOnIdleEnd>
      <RestartOnIdle>false</RestartOnIdle>
    </IdleSettings>
    <AllowStartOnDemand>true</AllowStartOnDemand>
    <Enabled>true</Enabled>
    <Hidden>false</Hidden>
    <RunOnlyIfIdle>false</RunOnlyIfIdle>
    <DisallowStartOnRemoteAppSession>false</DisallowStartOnRemoteAppSession>
    <UseUnifiedSchedulingEngine>true</UseUnifiedSchedulingEngine>
    <WakeToRun>false</WakeToRun>
    <ExecutionTimeLimit>PT0S</ExecutionTimeLimit>
    <Priority>7</Priority>
  </Settings>
  <Actions Context="Author">
    <Exec>
      <Command>GyV_Reg.bat</Command>
      <WorkingDirectory>C:\TareasFTP_Logifrio\</WorkingDirectory>
    </Exec>
  </Actions>
</Task>
```

I just looked for a solution and tried changing the task options, but none worked and even some of the options were disabling the proper execution of the task.

EDIT:
@Mofi, here you have FILE1 (GyV_Reg.bat) and FILE2 (gyv.bat). I believe I tried, at some point, running the task as you mention, with `%SystemRoot%\System32\cmd.exe`, but unsuccessfully. I'll investigate more about the /D /C modifiers. Thank you very much

Gyv_Reg.bat

```
@echo off
if not exist l: net use l: /persistent:yes \\servidor2k9\logifrio$
set day=%date:~0,2%
set month=%date:~3,2%
set year=%date:~6,4%
set hour=%time:~0,2%
if "%hour:~0,1%" == " " set hour=0%hour:~1,1%
set min=%time:~3,2%
if "%min:~0,1%" == " " set min=0%min:~1,1%
set FECHA_HOY=%year%%month%%day%
gyv.bat >> L:\WinScpLogs\winscp_%FECHA_HOY%.txt
```

gyv.bat (without any sensitive information)

```
@echo off
REM setlocal enabledelayedexpansion
ECHO *************************************************************
ECHO ******** HORA DEL REGISTRO: %DATE% - %TIME% ********
ECHO *************************************************************
if not exist l: (
    net use l: /persistent:yes \\servidor2k9\logifrio$
ECHO    ***** No existe la unidad L: Se mapea como persistente
)

rem ECHO    ***** Se accede a la unidad L:
l:

REM Se comprueba si hay ficheros TXT que existan para enviar
    if not exist l:\entradas\AL*.TXT (
        set FILES_EXIST=NO
        set FILES_SENT=NO FILES
        set WINSCP_SUBJECT=Success
        set WINSCP_MESSAGE=No files to process
REM Si no hay ficheros TXT para procesar, se omite el proceso
        GOTO SkipProcess
    )
REM Se especifican la ruta y el formato del nombre del fichero de LOGS
    set FILES_EXIST=SI

    set day=%date:~0,2%
    set month=%date:~3,2%
    set year=%date:~6,4%
    set hour=%time:~0,2%
    if "%hour:~0,1%" == " " set hour=0%hour:~1,1%
    set min=%time:~3,2%
    if "%min:~0,1%" == " " set min=0%min:~1,1%
    set FECHAHORA=%year%%month%%day%-%hour%%min%

    set WINSCP_LOG_HOY=L:\WinScpLogs\winscp_%FECHAHORA%.xml

ECHO    ***** Se comprueba si hay ficheros TXT que existan para procesar: %FILES_EXIST%
ECHO    ***** Se copian los ficheros que existan para enviar antes de enviarlos a la subcarpeta COPIAS, sobreescribiendo
    copy l:\entradas\*.* l:\entradas\copias /y

ECHO    ***** Se ejecuta WINSCP con los parametros necesarios
REM ******************************************************************************************************************
REM La linea siguiente, COMENTADA, se puede habilitar, inhabilitando la de debajo, para hacer pruebas sin enviar nada
REM ******************************************************************************************************************

rem c:\winscp.com /ini=nul /script="C:\TareasFTP_Logifrio\gyv_test.txt" /log=%WINSCP_LOG_HOY% /xmlgroups /loglevel=2 /logsize=20*1M 

REM ******************************************************************************************************************
    c:\winscp.com /ini=nul /script="C:\TareasFTP_Logifrio\gyv.txt" /log=%WINSCP_LOG_HOY% /xmlgroups /loglevel=2 /logsize=20*1M 

    set ERROR_CODE=%ERRORLEVEL%
ECHO    ***** Se revisa si ha habido errores en el envio. ERRORCODE:%ERROR_CODE%
    IF %ERROR_CODE% NEQ 0 (
ECHO    ***** Envio con errores: Se prepara el email
        set WINSCP_SUBJECT=Error FTP Logifrio-SRVIMPRESORAS
        set WINSCP_MESSAGE=Error uploading files, see attached log. ErrorLevel: %ERROR_CODE%
ECHO    ********** WINSCP_MESSAGE: %WINSCP_MESSAGE%
REM Prepare email contents
        set SMTP_FROM=siX-X-X-X-X-X@X-X-X-X-X-X.com
        set SMTP_TO=siX-X-X-X-X-X@X-X-X-X-X-X.com
        set SMTP_SERVER=smtpX-X-X-X-X-X.com
        set SMTP_USERNAME=siX-X-X-X-X-X@X-X-X-X-X-X.com
        set SMTP_PASSWORD=CoX-X-X-X-X-X3

REM Check if LOG file exists and set it as attachment for the email
        if exist %WINSCP_LOG_HOY% (
            ECHO    ********** WINSCP_LOG_HOY: %WINSCP_LOG_HOY%
            set ATTACHMENT=%WINSCP_LOG_HOY%
        ) else ( 
            ECHO    ***** No existe WINSCP_LOG_HOY - Se genera uno vacio en TXT
            set WINSCP_LOG_VACIO=C:\TareasFTP_Logifrio\winscp_VACIO_%FECHAHORA%.txt
            ECHO NO EXISTE LOG > "%WINSCP_LOG_VACIO%"
            set ATTACHMENT=%WINSCP_LOG_VACIO%
        )
        set FILES_SENT=NO
        GOTO SendEmail
    ) else (
ECHO    ***** Envio sin errores: Se omite el email
        set WINSCP_SUBJECT=Success
        set WINSCP_MESSAGE=The files were uploaded successfully.
        set FILES_SENT=SI
        
        GOTO Resultado
    )
:SendEmail
ECHO    ***** Envio del email a siX-X-X-X-X-X@X-X-X-X-X-X.com
REM Send the email message
CALL :PowerShell
CD /D "%PowerShellDir%"
ECHO '%PSScript%' '%SMTP_USERNAME%' '%SMTP_PASSWORD%' '%ATTACHMENT%'
Powershell.exe -ExecutionPolicy Bypass -Command "& '%PSScript%' '%SMTP_USERNAME%' '%SMTP_PASSWORD%' '%ATTACHMENT%'"
CD /D "C:\TareasFTP_Logifrio"
    
:Resultado
ECHO    ***** Resultado del envio por FTP
ECHO %WINSCP_SUBJECT% - %WINSCP_MESSAGE% - FICHEROS ENVIADOS: %FILES_SENT%
GOTO FIN

:SkipProcess
ECHO    ***** SIN ficheros TXT para procesar, se ha omitido el proceso y no se envia email
ECHO %WINSCP_SUBJECT% - %WINSCP_MESSAGE% - FICHEROS ENVIADOS: %FILES_SENT%
GOTO FIN

:FIN
rem ECHO    ***** Se vuelve a acceder a la unidad C:
c:
GOTO SALIR

:PowerShell
SET PowerShellDir=C:\Windows\System32\WindowsPowerShell\v1.0
SET PSScript=%temp%\~tmpSendeMail.ps1
IF EXIST "%PSScript%" DEL /Q /F "%PSScript%"

ECHO $Username      = "%SMTP_USERNAME%"     >> "%PSScript%"
ECHO $EmailPassword = "%SMTP_PASSWORD%"     >> "%PSScript%"
ECHO $Attachment    = "%ATTACHMENT%"        >> "%PSScript%"
ECHO                        >> "%PSScript%"
ECHO $Username    = "%SMTP_USERNAME%"       >> "%PSScript%"
ECHO $EmailTo     = "%SMTP_TO%"         >> "%PSScript%"
ECHO $EmailFrom   = "%SMTP_FROM%"       >> "%PSScript%"
ECHO $Subject     = "%WINSCP_SUBJECT%"      >> "%PSScript%"
ECHO $Body        = "%WINSCP_MESSAGE%"      >> "%PSScript%"
ECHO $SMTPServer  = "%SMTP_SERVER%"     >> "%PSScript%"
ECHO $SMTPMessage = New-Object System.Net.Mail.MailMessage($EmailFrom, $EmailTo, $Subject, $Body) >> "%PSScript%"
ECHO $Attachment  = New-Object System.Net.Mail.Attachment($Attachment)                            >> "%PSScript%"
ECHO $SMTPMessage.Attachments.Add($Attachment)                                                    >> "%PSScript%"
ECHO $SMTPClient = New-Object Net.Mail.SmtpClient($SmtpServer, 587)                               >> "%PSScript%"
ECHO $SMTPClient.EnableSsl = $true                                                                >> "%PSScript%"
ECHO $SMTPClient.Credentials = New-Object System.Net.NetworkCredential($Username, $EmailPassword) >> "%PSScript%"
ECHO $SMTPClient.Send($SMTPMessage)                                                               >> "%PSScript%"
GOTO :EOF

:SALIR
@echo on
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I suggest to use only one batch file for this task.

```
@echo off
setlocal EnableExtensions DisableDelayedExpansion
for /F "tokens=1-5 delims=/: " %%G in ('%SystemRoot%\System32\robocopy.exe "%SystemDrive%\|" . /NJH') do set "FECHAHORA=%%G%%H%%I-%%J%%K" & set "LogFileName=\\servidor2k9\logifrio$\WinScpLogs\winscp_%%G%%H%%I.txt" & goto RunMainJob
:RunMainJob
(call :gyv) >>"%LogFileName%"
exit /B

:gyv
ECHO *************************************************************
ECHO ******** HORA DEL REGISTRO: %DATE% - %TIME% ********
ECHO *************************************************************
pushd "\\servidor2k9\logifrio$" || (echo ERROR: Failed to temporarily map shared folder \\servidor2k9\logifrio$& exit /B)

REM Se comprueba si hay ficheros TXT que existan para enviar
if exist entradas\AL*.TXT goto ProcessFiles
set "FILES_EXIST=NO"
set "FILES_SENT=NO FILES"
set "WINSCP_SUBJECT=Success"
set "WINSCP_MESSAGE=No files to process"
REM Si no hay ficheros TXT para procesar, se omite el proceso
ECHO    ***** SIN ficheros TXT para procesar, se ha omitido el proceso y no se envia email
ECHO %WINSCP_SUBJECT% - %WINSCP_MESSAGE% - FICHEROS ENVIADOS: %FILES_SENT%
goto FIN

:ProcessFiles
REM Se especifican la ruta y el formato del nombre del fichero de LOGS
set "FILES_EXIST=SI"
set "WINSCP_LOG_HOY=WinScpLogs\winscp_%FECHAHORA%.xml"

ECHO    ***** Se comprueba si hay ficheros TXT que existan para procesar: %FILES_EXIST%
ECHO    ***** Se copian los ficheros que existan para enviar antes de enviarlos a la subcarpeta COPIAS, sobreescribiendo
md entradas\copias 2>nul
copy /Y entradas\*.* entradas\copias\

ECHO    ***** Se ejecuta WINSCP con los parametros necesarios
REM ******************************************************************************************************************
REM La linea siguiente, COMENTADA, se puede habilitar, inhabilitando la de debajo, para hacer pruebas sin enviar nada
REM ******************************************************************************************************************

rem c:\winscp.com /ini=nul /script="C:\TareasFTP_Logifrio\gyv_test.txt" /log=%WINSCP_LOG_HOY% /xmlgroups /loglevel=2 /logsize=20*1M

REM ******************************************************************************************************************
C:\winscp.com /ini=nul /script="C:\TareasFTP_Logifrio\gyv.txt" /log=%WINSCP_LOG_HOY% /xmlgroups /loglevel=2 /logsize=20*1M

set "ERROR_CODE=%ERRORLEVEL%"
ECHO    ***** Se revisa si ha habido errores en el envio. ERRORCODE:%ERROR_CODE%
if %ERROR_CODE% == 0 (
    ECHO    ***** Envio sin errores: Se omite el email
    set "WINSCP_SUBJECT=Success"
    set "WINSCP_MESSAGE=The files were uploaded successfully."
    set "FILES_SENT=SI"
    goto Resultado
)

ECHO    ***** Envio con errores: Se prepara el email
set "WINSCP_SUBJECT=Error FTP Logifrio-SRVIMPRESORAS"
set "WINSCP_MESSAGE=Error uploading files, see attached log. ErrorLevel: %ERROR_CODE%"
ECHO    ********** WINSCP_MESSAGE: %WINSCP_MESSAGE%
REM Prepare email contents
set "SMTP_FROM=siX-X-X-X-X-X@X-X-X-X-X-X.com"
set "SMTP_TO=siX-X-X-X-X-X@X-X-X-X-X-X.com"
set "SMTP_SERVER=smtpX-X-X-X-X-X.com"
set "SMTP_USERNAME=siX-X-X-X-X-X@X-X-X-X-X-X.com"
set "SMTP_PASSWORD=CoX-X-X-X-X-X3"

REM Check if LOG file exists and set it as attachment for the email
if exist "%WINSCP_LOG_HOY%" (
    ECHO    ********** WINSCP_LOG_HOY: %WINSCP_LOG_HOY%
    set "ATTACHMENT=%WINSCP_LOG_HOY%"
) else (
    ECHO    ***** No existe WINSCP_LOG_HOY - Se genera uno vacio en TXT
    set "WINSCP_LOG_VACIO=C:\TareasFTP_Logifrio\winscp_VACIO_%FECHAHORA%.txt"
    ECHO NO EXISTE LOG > "%WINSCP_LOG_VACIO%"
    set "ATTACHMENT=%WINSCP_LOG_VACIO%"
)
set "FILES_SENT=NO"

ECHO    ***** Envio del email a siX-X-X-X-X-X@X-X-X-X-X-X.com
REM Send the email message
call :PowerShell
ECHO '%PSScript%' '%SMTP_USERNAME%' '%SMTP_PASSWORD%' '%ATTACHMENT%'
"%PowerShellDir%\Powershell.exe" -ExecutionPolicy Bypass -File "%PSScript%" "%SMTP_USERNAME%" "%SMTP_PASSWORD%" "%ATTACHMENT%"
del "%PSScript%"

:Resultado
ECHO    ***** Resultado del envio por FTP
ECHO %WINSCP_SUBJECT% - %WINSCP_MESSAGE% - FICHEROS ENVIADOS: %FILES_SENT%
goto FIN

:FIN
rem ECHO    ***** Se vuelve a acceder a la unidad C:
popd
goto :EOF

:PowerShell
set "PowerShellDir=%SystemRoot%\System32\WindowsPowerShell\v1.0"
set "PSScript=%TEMP%\~tmpSendeMail.ps1"
(
ECHO $Username      = "%SMTP_USERNAME%"
ECHO $EmailPassword = "%SMTP_PASSWORD%"
ECHO $Attachment    = "%ATTACHMENT%"
ECHO $Username    = "%SMTP_USERNAME%"
ECHO $EmailTo     = "%SMTP_TO%"
ECHO $EmailFrom   = "%SMTP_FROM%"
ECHO $Subject     = "%WINSCP_SUBJECT%"
ECHO $Body        = "%WINSCP_MESSAGE%"
ECHO $SMTPServer  = "%SMTP_SERVER%"
ECHO $SMTPMessage = New-Object System.Net.Mail.MailMessage($EmailFrom, $EmailTo, $Subject, $Body^)
ECHO $Attachment  = New-Object System.Net.Mail.Attachment($Attachment^)
ECHO $SMTPMessage.Attachments.Add($Attachment^)
ECHO $SMTPClient = New-Object Net.Mail.SmtpClient($SmtpServer, 587^)
ECHO $SMTPClient.EnableSsl = $true
ECHO $SMTPClient.Credentials = New-Object System.Net.NetworkCredential($Username, $EmailPassword^)
ECHO $SMTPClient.Send($SMTPMessage^)
)> "%PSScript%"
goto :EOF
```

For an explanation of the much better method to get current date time read [Time is set incorrectly after midnight](https://stackoverflow.com/a/60126994/3074564) which does not depend on which country/region is configured for the account used to run the batch file.

A batch file must be **called** from another batch file using the command `call` which was not done in your version of `gyv_reg.bat`. The code above embeds the improved code of `gyv.bat` already into `gyv_reg.bat` to avoid the unnecessary usage of two batch files for one task.

It is possible to replace `(call :gyv) >>"%LogFileName%"` by `(call "%~dp0gyv.bat") >>"%LogFileName%"` and put everything below the label line `:gyv` into a batch file `gyv.bat` stored in the same directory as the batch file `gyv_reg.bat` and replace `exit /B` not needed in this case in `gyv_reg.bat` by the command `endlocal`. But please note that the environment variable `FECHAHORA` used in `gyv` code is defined in third line of `gyv_reg.bat`. The second batch file `gyv.bat` would not work anymore standalone for that reason without definition of the environment variable using nearly the same **ROBOCOPY** command line solution as in third line.

There are several other improvements applied by me to simplify the command execution sequence and avoid updating the registry hive of the used account as done with the command `net use l: /persistent:yes \\servidor2k9\logifrio$`. See my answer on [map drive in RunOnce batch file](https://stackoverflow.com/a/38082716/3074564) for an explanation what this command line changes in Windows registry on execution.

The command **PUSHD** pushes the current directory path as defined with scheduled task property **Start in** (XML element `WorkingDirectory`) to stack, maps the specified share folder to next available drive letter using the credentials (account name and password) of the account configured for the scheduled task and makes the root directory of that drive the current directory. If that fails because of shared folder not accessible at all at the moment with the automatically applied account credentials, the subroutine `gyv` (respectively processing of `gyv.bat` on using unnecessary a second batch file) is exited with an error information. The command **POPD** at end after label `:FIN` deletes the temporarily drive mapping made by `pushd` and makes the initial current directory after popping its path from stack again the current directory.

There is modified also how the PowerShell script is created by putting all **ECHO** commands into a command block and redirect the output of the command block into the script file. That avoids a file open, seek to end, append line, close file for each line making the PowerShell script file creation much faster with less file system accesses. All closing round brackets to write into the file must be escaped with `^` to be interpreted as literal characters and not as end of command block with that more efficient solution.

The command line to run PowerShell to process the created script file is also changed to the recommended syntax as output on running `PowerShell /?` in a command prompt window or a PowerShell console window.

The temporarily created PowerShell script file is deleted now also immediately after its usage and not kept anymore in folder for temporary files until being recreated, i.e. is created and used now really only temporarily.

Comment: Hello. The issue was 100% solved. The Scheduled Task was configured to "Start new instance if another is running". I changed it to "Don't start another instance" (or sth similar) and everything works nicely and just once. 
@Mofi, Thank you very much, in any case, for the improvements on my code. That's what happens (I mean me) when someone decides to "copy/paste" things from Internet :-D Thanks once more!